# Do we use the noun "scrape" to refer to a damage caused by being scraped on the wall?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We often use the noun "**scrape**" to refer to skin injury caused by rubbing the skin on something rough.

For example, "**I scraped my knee on the wall and now I have a scrape**".

[image]

Now, look at this picture, my children scraped the wall with some sharp objects and it left some shallow holes on the wall like this.

Are these shallow holes called "**scrapes**"?

For example, "**there are so many scrapes on the wall**"

Comment: I think they'd more likely be called *[deep] **scratches*** or ***gouges***, but ***scrapes*** is at least "acceptable" as a noun usage here.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey, I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can talk about "scrapes" in an inanimate object.

Answer (score 0):

I think they'd more likely be called [deep] scratches or gouges, but scrapes is at least "acceptable" as a noun usage here. –
FumbleFingers